# How to make call back for async/await function

Tags: javascript, async-await

My async function in JavaScript reads a file and then puts the result into a specific div.

```
async function loadContent( id, file ) {
    var response = await fetch( file );
    var text = await response.text();
    document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = text;
}
```

I use it like this now:

```
loadContent("pagesmaxspan", "../export/" + `<?php echo $randomid ?>` + ".variable");
```

but when i try to get the variable it won't work

```
var myvar = $("pagesmaxspan").textContent; // <<--- this does not work
```

with delay it would look like this:

```
var myvar = "";

setTimeout(function() {
    myvar = $("pagesmaxspan").textContent;
}, 100);
```

How can I do this without using `setTimeout`?

Comment: `loadContent(...).then(callbackfunctionhere)`, also `$("pagesmaxspan")` this looks for an element named `pagesmaxspan` ie `<pagesmaxspan>` do you actually have such an element being added to the page, or did you mean to use a class or some other selector?

Comment: really, that easy ?! Thnaks, I'll try it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the callback to the function `loadContent`

```
async function loadContent( id, file, callBack = false) {
    var response = await fetch( file );
    var text = await response.text();
    document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = text;

    //check if callback is function
    if (callBack && callBack.constructor && callBack.call && callBack.apply)
    {
        callBack();
    }
}
```

call it with

```
loadContent("pagesmaxspan", "../export/" + `<?php echo $randomid ?>` + ".variable",
 function(){
    var myvar = $("pagesmaxspan").textContent;
});
```

Comment: No, don't add a callback parameter to a function returning a promise.

Comment: "*check if callback is function*" - why not just use `typeof` for that?!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `loadContent` there's no `await` there, so you just get a Promise back from the `async` function, and code execution moves on.

That's why the suggestion from @Patrick above works, putting the code you need to execute afterward inside the `then`.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a sample for @kshetline answer, this should work.

```
loadContent("pagesmaxspan", "../export/" + `<?php echo $randomid ?>` + ".variable")
.then(() => {
   console.log($("pagesmaxspan").textContent);
})
```

Comment: so is this the correct answer now? I'm confused.. what should I use now, the example of @Mouser worked out fine.. what's to problem with his solution?

Comment: @Miger IMHO, having a callback in an async function (which returns a Promise as all async function do), is bad practice in most cases. It adds redundancy and confusion. Using promises, the code is shorter and yet more flexible: https://medium.com/@anny.huynh32/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-async-await-a66668d44c7b

Comment: Is it inherently wrong to use `Mousers` code? I'm still confused...